# How can use MP45DT02 and CS43L22 DAC with STM32F4?

Tags: sensor, audio, stm32f4, mems, mems-microphone

I'm doing an application with [MP45DT02 MEMS audio sensor omnidirectional digital microphone](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00025467.pdf).

I'd like to use a [STM32F4 MCU](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1577?sc=stm32f4) to control it, but I don't know much about it. Can I take input from the audio sensor and read it with the [CS43L22 DAC unit](http://www.cirrus.com/en/products/cs43l22.html)? If so, how?

Also, are there any libraries available that I can use to drive these components?

Comment: Start off with embedding some links to the devices and try and clean up your question a bit using capital letters where appropriate and finishing sentences a bit better; "i cant it" isn't a proper end to a sentence. The bit about libraries - you are losing me here.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a device with digital output using PDM ([Pulse Density Modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-density_modulation)), which is the 1-bit oversampled output of a sigma-delta ADC-- it's similar to what's used in SACD. A microcontroller should be able to convert it to the more usual PCM format by digital filtering and resampling, provided it has enough processing power. Since the CS43L22 appears to take PCM data for input, you have no escape but to perform this conversion if you want to use it.

An alternative, which I believe should work, is to just output the data digitally via a GPIO, perform analog filtering (lowpass filtering at a cutoff of, say, 20 kHz), and then input it to an audio amplifier.

Comment: so first of all thanks for your clarification
and also are there any any application that i take a look at then help me out there,if you got something like this application,i'm very appreciated if you share it with me.
thank you
have a nice day